# Problem with \' in URLencoding

Tags: java, url

I am working on Java. Here is my code

```
response = URLEncoder.encode(response, "UTF-8").replaceAll("\\+", "%20");
```

Problem comes when there is a ' (single quote) in the string response. It gets encoded to \'.

eg -  'Collective Dynamics of Complex Networks' comes as

\'Collective Dynamics of Complex Networks\'

I want it to remain as it is. What should I do?

Comment: Are you sure? `'` encodes to `%27` for me, and backslash escapes have nothing to do with URL encoding.

Comment: @Pete: thats what I am getting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may work:

```
String after = before.replace("\\'", "'");
```

This assigns to `after`, `before` with `\'` replaced with `'`.

#### API links

- [`String replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29)

  - Replaces each substring of this string that matches the literal target sequence with the specified literal replacement sequence. The replacement proceeds from the beginning of the string to the end, for example, replacing `"aa"` with `"b"` in the string `"aaa"` will result in `"ba"` rather than `"ab"`.